# Can't update products in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, backend

When I try to update a product nothing happens and I got the following messages in logs:

```
2019-05-16T07:19:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /home/mywebsite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2019-05-16T07:19:30+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Varien_Object::addData() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/mywebsite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 513 and defined  in /home/mywebsite/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 243
2019-05-16T07:19:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/mywebsite/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 245
2019-05-16T07:19:31+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of PushAlert_WebPush_Codeblock_Addblock::getData() should be compatible with Varien_Object::getData($key = '', $index = NULL)  in /home/mywebsite/public_html/app/code/local/Pushalert/WebPush/Codeblock/Addblock.php on line 209
```

And the browser console gives the error (403 Forbidden):

```
POST
https://mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/validate/id/5531/key/5123ac4d9bd8d537002640b4716398ee/?isAjax=true 403 (Forbidden)
request @ prototype.js:1530
```

I have tried to clear and disable the cache and the compilation with no result.

What do you think is the problem?